# SQL Server Database - Hidden Fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, hidden-field

I'm implementing CRUD on my silverlight application, however I don't want to implement the Delete functionality in the traditional way, instead I'd like to set the data to be hidden instead inside the database.

Does anyone know of a way of doing this with an SQL Server Database?

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Udi Dahan had a pretty good blog post on this.   http://www.udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending Lukasz' idea, a datetime column is useful too.

- NULL = current
- Value = when soft deleted

This adds simple versioning that a bit column can not which may work better

Comment: +1: date column would be kind-of *audit* **DeletedAt** field as well in this case. one might want to trace the **DeletedBy** in addition to that.

Answer (score 9):

You can add another column to the table "deleted" which has value 0 or 1, and display only those records with deleted = 0.

```
ALTER TABLE TheTable ADD COLUMN deleted BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

You can also create view which takes only undeleted rows.

```
CREATE VIEW undeleted AS SELECT * FROM TheTable WHERE deleted = 0
```

And you delete command would look like this:

```
UPDATE TheTable SET deleted = 1 WHERE id = ...
```

Comment: best way to do it from what i've seen.

Answer (score 2):

In most situations I would rather archive the deleted rows to an archive table with a delete trigger.  This way I can also capture who deleted each row and the deleted rows don't impact my performance.  You can then create a view that unions both tables together when you want to include the deleted ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as [Lukasz Lysik suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400574/sql-server-database-hidden-fields/1400613#1400613), and have a field that serves as a flag for "deleted" rows, filtering them out when you don't want them showing up. I've used that in a number of applications.

An alternate suggestion would be to add an extra status assignment if there's a pre-existing status code. For example, in a class attendance app we use internally an attendance record could be "Imported", "Registered", "Completed", "Incomplete", etc.* - we added a "Deleted" option for times where there are unintentional duplicates. That way we have a record and we're not just throwing a new column at the problem.

*That is the display name for a numeric code used behind the scenes. Just clarifying. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with triggers**

If you are friends with DB trigger, then you might consider:

- add a `DeletedAt and DeletedBy` columns to your tables
- create a view for each tables (ex: for table `Customer` have a `CustomerView` view, which would filter out rows that have `DeletedAt` not null (idea of *gbn* with date columns)
- all your CRUD operations perform as usual, but not on the `Customer` table, but on the `CustomerView`
- add `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger that would mark the row as delete instead of physically deleting it.

  - you may want to do a bit more complex stuff there like ensuring that all FK references to this row are also "logically" deleted in order to still have *logical* **referential integrity**

I you choose to use this pattern, I would probably name my tables differently like `TCustomer,` and views just `Customer` for clarity of client code.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful with this kind of implementation because soft deletes break referential integrity and you have to enforce integrity in your entities using custom logic.

Comment: I think he means it doesn't break referential integrity. Therefore if you logically delete something then it will not force you to logically delete any related data.

Comment: Even so, in a properly set up query it still won't make a difference. Especially since the OP clearly is looking to retain the data.